# How Do I add frontend edit feature to component?

Tags: joomla2.5

I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Using_the_database) to build a component. Everything works as expected. Now I am confused on how to add an edit feature to the frontend. A uses (with appropriate rights) should be able to click an edit link and edit the data displayed by the component as well as add new data. Just like in the backend.

I have the feeling that I miss something obvious, but I couldn't get my code to work. I thouhgt, I could just replicate the backend code, but with no success.

Is there a tutorial or other hint you could give me?

Thanks
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right: I missed something obvious, because it's all there.

Look at [this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Using_the_editor_in_a_component). It guides you through the process of integrating an editor to the frontend. But it also shows

- how to display an edit form
  and
- save the data.

Best regards
Sascha